# Deleting a commit interactively in git rebase that was selected for editing

Tags: git, git-rebase

I prepare a repo for publication and need to fully remove certain internal information from its history. This data can be in various files which I have to check/prune manually. Note that not the whole file should be deleted, just certain content.

When I do `git rebase -i --root` I can mark all commits that (a) **potentially** need modification as `edit` and those that (b) need to go completely as `drop`. (Note: The list of commits to review is not too long and was optained by using `git log --stat | grep 'commit\|name1\|name2\|...'`.) While screening the commits of type (a) I might find one that actually needs to be dropped completely. For this I tried `rebase --skip` but, to my surprise, that still leaves the commit in place.

How can I remove a commit during `git rebase` which I selected to `edit` initially?

Example:

```bash
$ git init
$ for COM in A B C; do touch $COM; git add  $COM; git commit -m "add $COM"; done
$ git rebase -i --root
<mark all as 'edit'>

<modify file and change commit>
$ echo A > A; git add A; git rebase --continue

<commit needs to go away>
$ git rebase --skip

<modify file and change commit>
$ echo C > C; git add C; git rebase --continue
```

File `B` still exists after this.

Comment: This is a question torek-level. I assume that git was able to commit and it is waiting for you to edit the revision. What you should do is ask git to go back one revision.... I would simply do `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, then the revision is gone... _but_ I would assume that resetting that way will also wipe the rebase process... that's a question for torek. Perhaps it's possible to go `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, then clean the tree and then resume? Interesting question. Upvoting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `git rebase --skip`, use

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git rebase --continue
```

The `git reset` will remove the commit.
`git rebase --skip` doesn't remove the commit that's already been applied at that point.

Comment: @grp does running `git reset --hard` wipe out the rebase process?

Comment: @eftshift0 Nope, I tested this with the same commands as in OP except what this answer suggests replacing.

Comment: @eftshift0: This is correct, and is also the reason that, when you mark a commit `edit`, the advice that rebase prints at this point is to make changes and use `git commit --amend`: rebase has already copied the commit so you want to push it out of the way, whether you're using `--amend` (which does that internally) or `git reset --hard HEAD^` (which is an explicit command to do that).